# Rotate object to face the mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

I can't figure out how to properly rotate an object in ThreeJS. The object is a simple box geometry that is rendered from above somewhere on the screen.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Candleout/pen/OJvxpPY) with the full code.

The object is supposed to rotate around it's own Y axis (the vertical axis) to always face the mouse cursor. I can get it to rotate as the cursor moves around the global axis in the middle of the screen, but not when the cursor moves around the object's own local axis.

**UPDATE**: I got it to work using ray casting. See code further down or in the codepen.

The orthographic camera is set up like this:

```
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    window.innerWidth / - 2, // left
    window.innerWidth / 2, // right
    window.innerHeight / 2, // top
    window.innerHeight / - 2, // bottom
    0, // near
    1000 ); // far

camera.position.set(0, 0, 500)
camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
```

The object is set up like this:

```
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: "grey" } );
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

Code for handling rotation at mousemove:

```
function onMouseMove(event) {
    // Get mouse position
    let mousePos = new THREE.Vector2();
    mousePos.set(
        (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, // x
        -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1); // y

    // Calculate angle
    let angle = Math.atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x);

    // Add rotation to object
    mesh.rotation.set(
    0, // x
    angle, // y
    0) // z
}
```

I have also tried

```
mesh.rotateY(angle)
```

but this only makes the object spinn like a helicopter.

It's obvious the rotation needs to be based on the relationship between the cursor and the local axis rather than the global axis. I just can't figure out how to achieve that.

**UPDATE**

I have added a codepen at the top of the question.

**UPDATE**

I got it to work using the following method with ray casting.

```
let plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), 0);
let pointOfIntersection = new THREE.Vector3();
let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

let mousePos = new THREE.Vector2();
mousePos.set(
    (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, // x
    -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1))

raycaster.setFromCamera(mousePos, camera);
raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, pointOfIntersection);
mesh.lookAt(pointOfIntersection)
```

Comment: The only issue I see is that your camera is looking down the Z-axis, but your box is spinning around the y-axis. Maybe try setting `mesh.rotation.z = angle` so it spins along the same axis.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. The orientation of the rotation looks fine. The issue is that the object doesn't turn around to face the cursor if the cursor moves around the object itself. The rotation only works if the cursor moves around the the global axis in the middle of the screen. In other words, the rotation is based on the global axis instread of the local axis of the object. To be clear, the object is not positioned at the global axis (origo) in the centre of the screen.

Comment: In that case you'll need to use a raycaster to intersect a plane to find a 3D point in space, [like in this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_raycaster_texture). Maybe you can use a giant plane that covers the whole screen. Once you have that `Vector3` position, you can use [the Mesh's `.lookAt()` method](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=object#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt) like `mesh.lookAt(position)` so it points in that direction. Once you have it working, make the giant plane invisible with `plane.visible = false`

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me. I tried this earlier, but the outcome was the same as before. You can see the code in my updated question. There seems to be a mixup between the local and global axis.

Comment: Correction: the outcome is similar but not identical. Tomorrow I will attempt to create a codepen with the full code. I will be very grateful if you have time to take another look tomorrow!

Comment: Codepen: https://codepen.io/Candleout/pen/OJvxpPY Notice how circling the global axis with the pointer makes the box rotate. That's the behaviour I want from circling around the box itself! I get a similar result when trying to implement ray casting.

Comment: I got it to work using ray casting. I only had to set the distance between the plane and the origin to zero. See the codepen. My only issue now is that the object (alternatively the whole scene) is actually supposed to be rotated in the x direction by 32. I left this out of the question because I didn't think it would be relevant. As it stands, the lookAt() replaces the object's original rotation. If I rotate the whole scene instead of the object, the lookAt() rotation is no longer fixed to a 2D plane, as it should be, but instead makes the object look around in three dimensions.

Comment: I solved this, by adding a bit of rotation after the ray casting. targetRotation = 32; angleDiff = box.rotation.x - 32; box.rotation.x = angleDiff;

Comment: Glad you figured it out!